# Disable CheckedListBox Autoscroll on item checked?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, checkedlistbox

Situation: I have a CheckedListBox with a horizontal scroll bar enabled with CheckOnClick set to true. The size of the CheckListBox is such that two column of items is shown.

Issue: When the user clicks on an item in the second column to check it on or off, the horizontal scroll bar automatically shifts the entire row such that it's in the first column.

Question: How do I disable the CheckedListBox from automatically shifting? I took a look at the properties but I can't seem to find one that would disable it, does the answer lie in inheriting the CheckedListBox and overriding methods?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

if you always want to go back to the top-left item (scroll back all the way to the left), just select item[0] programmatically on SelectedIndexChanged... this will still fire off the "check" and actually DO the "check on check off", but will return to the first item in the list...

like this:

```
private void lst_Servers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lst_Servers.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: when you size your table you have to do it very carefully, ensure that the rightmost column is entirely within the visible area, otherwise if you edit a cell in that column the table would scroll left...